# Cross platform ( iOS and Android ) chat does not work with chat21 SDK

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, chatsdk

We are using chat-SDK chat21 for android and iOS.

https://github.com/chat21/chat21-ios-demo

https://github.com/chat21/chat21-android-sdk

Under my firebase account, I have 2 applications 1 for android and another for iOS.

For Android, we are using `google-service.json` file with `App ID`.

For iOS, we are using `GoogleService-info.plist` file for configuration chat21 SDK

But, When I do message from android the iOS does not receive any message the same thing happening from iOS to android application.

It's because we are using different applications? ( project settings -> Your apps section ) both have different App ID though App ID is only used In android application.

The internal chat I mean iOS to iOS and android to android chat works absolutely fine cross-platform chat does not work.

[image]

[image]

Let me know if I am lacking something in configuration so can fix quickly thanks

**Updates 02 JULY**

[image]

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);

ChatManager.startWithEmailAndPassword(this, [APP_ID],
[YOUR_EMAIL], [YOUR_PASSWORD], new ChatAuthentication.OnChatLoginCallback() {
@override
public void onChatLoginSuccess(IChatUser currentUser) {
ChatManager.getInstance().createContactFor(currentUser.getId(), currentUser.getEmail(),
[YOUR_FIRST_NAME], [YOUR_LAST_NAME], new OnContactCreatedCallback() {
@override
public void onContactCreatedSuccess(ChatRuntimeException exception) {
if (exception == null) {
ChatUI.getInstance().openConversationsListActivity();
} else {
// TODO: handle the exception
}
}
});
}

@override
public void onChatLoginError(Exception e) {
// TODO: 22/02/18
}
});
```

Above android code which uses app id to connect with firebase and in iOS getting app_id from plist file. both APP_Id are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By replacing `APP_ID` with `"chat"` (the same name of the iOS tree).Previously, I was using  Firebase `APP_ID`, which refers to Firebase. This is the **tenant name of my app and must be the same for all the clients using chat**. which resolved the problem! Thanks to the team!